# Parsing JSON object in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have JSON object as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Project": {
            "id": "1",
            "project_name": "name"
        },
        "AllocationDetail": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "project_id": "1",
                "team_name": "ror",
                "week_percentage_work": "50",
                "in_today": "1",
                "actual_hours": "30",
                "remaining_hours": "100",
                "time_difference": null,
                "created": "2012-01-13 15:48:33",
                "modified": "2012-01-13 15:48:33"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "project_id": "1",
                "team_name": "php",
                "week_percentage_work": "40",
                "in_today": "2",
                "actual_hours": "50",
                "remaining_hours": "100",
                "time_difference": null,
                "created": "2012-01-13 15:49:40",
                "modified": "2012-01-13 15:49:40"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to parse data in android and store it into DB, but i m getting confused in Jsonobject
thanks

Comment: I have to srore data in a single table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a snippet code for parsing your json string. Kindly go through it:

```
    String response = <Your JSON String>;
            String Project = null;
            String AllocationDetail = null;
            try {
                JSONArray menuObject = new JSONArray(response);
                 for (int i = 0; i< menuObject.length(); i++) {
                        Project     =   menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("Project").toString();
                        System.out.println("Project="+Project);
                        AllocationDetail    =   menuObject.getJSONObject(i).getString("AllocationDetail").toString();
                        System.out.println("AllocationDetail="+AllocationDetail);
                 }
                 JSONObject jsonObject  =   new JSONObject(Project);
                 String id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                 System.out.println("id="+id);
                 String project_name = jsonObject.getString("project_name");
                 System.out.println("project_name="+project_name);

                 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(AllocationDetail);
                 for (int i = 0; i< jArray.length(); i++) {
                     String team_name       =   jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("team_name").toString();
                     System.out.println("team_name="+team_name);
                     String week_percentage_work        =   jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("week_percentage_work").toString();
                     System.out.println("week_percentage_work="+week_percentage_work);
                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Too complicate for the Newbies to understand, Please check my code for the simplest one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906490/parsing-json-object-in-android/14272501#14272501

Answer (score 3):

the best [JSON Tutorial](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) i have seen, I leared json parsing from this tutorial, hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for parsing JSON

- [`Google GSON`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [`JSON`](http://www.json.org/)

When your content of JSON is too complex and long enough you can prefer usin GSON its much easier to maintain than JSON parsing each value manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonlint.com to read your json better. It appears that the json that you have copied here is invalid.

Comment: sorry ... this is valid one.. :  [{"Project":{"id":"1","project_name":"pols"},"AllocationDetail":[{"id":"1","project_id":"1","team_name":"ror","week_percentage_work":"50","in_today":"1","actual_hours":"30","remaining_hours":"100","time_difference":null,"created":"2012-01-13 15:48:33","modified":"2012-01-13 15:48:33"},{"id":"2","project_id":"1","team_name":"php","week_percentage_work":"40","in_today":"2","actual_hours":"50","remaining_hours":"100","time_difference":null,"created":"2012-01-13 15:49:40","modified":"2012-01-13 15:49:40"}]}]

Answer (score 1):

```
String response = <Your JSON String>; // add your Json String here
response = response.replace("[","").replace("]",""); // Just remove all square braces
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response); //Convert the Json into Json Object
JSONObject jProject = json.getJSONObject("Project"); // get your project object
String  project_id = jProject.getString("id"); // Get the value of Id
String  project_name = jProject.getString("project_name"); // get the value of Project_name
```

The above code can be use many times as you want to parse the Json.
I know its too late, but It may help many people who are trying to find the same answer.
I was trying to find the same solution, but it was too hard to use the Accepted answer because of too many lines of codes, But I got the same results with hardly few lines of codes.